# Migrating Linux from SSD to SSD, with only 1 NVMe slot

Tags: ssd, migration

Currently, I have Windows and Ubuntu Linux set up on my 128 GB NVMe SSD. I'm planning on getting a 500 GB SSD, but since I only have one NVMe slot, I'm getting a USB adapter for it.

I'm going to copy over all of the partitions from the 128 GB SSD to the 500 GB SSD, in the same order on the drive as it was before. Obviously I'm going to want to resize them, to 200 GB for Windows and 300 GB for Linux (approximately). I've tried to resize and move an Ubuntu Linux before, but then the system couldn't find it and in turn, couldn't boot to it. Is there a way to resize and move the partitions while somehow changing where the system is looking for it? Would I have to copy it all over EXACTLY on Windows (Paragon Partition Manager), then install the SSD into the NVMe slot, then resize and move stuff within Ubuntu (which I assume will boot if all of the partitions are the same size and order as before)? And if so, how would I do this?

I just need a specific set of instructions to move and resize these partitions and allow it to boot successfully afterwards. Thank you.

Comment: If UEFI system, the gpt partitioning & boot may still be an issue. Gpt partitions have GUID in partition table, backup partition table at end of drive and in each partition. The GUIDs must match. You may be able to use gdisk to make repairs. With UEFI the boot entry in the UEFI is based on the GUID of the ESP and restoring partitions will not add UEFI boot entries. You may need to reinstall bootloaders or possibly just use efibootmgr to recreate the UEFI boot entries. If image copy, UEFI entry may work, but do not reboot with old drive connected until you change its UUIDs & GUIDs.

Comment: @oldfred could you explain this a little further? I don't have any idea what UUIDs and GUIDs are, and phrasing is a little confusing, especially the second sentence.

Comment: GUID: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table & UUIDs are used to identify partitions. to see UUIDs `lsblk -o name,mountpoint,label,size,fstype,fsused,uuid | egrep -v "^loop"` More on gpt: http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/whatsgpt.html  You just cannot copy one gpt partition which has a unique GUID to a new drive that has two partitions tables with different GUIDs. This is gettting down into a lot of technical details which are not necessary, but knowing you cannot copy just one gpt partition is important. I normally suggest new install.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I'd approach it.

1. Dump the partition table for an old disk: `sfdisk -d /dev/sda > sda.dump`
2. Edit the resulting file to match the new disk size (partitions start should be divisible by 2048), replace `sda` with `sdb`, e.g. using `sed`.
3. Restore the partitions on a new disk `sfdisk /dev/sdb < sda.dump`

Use `e2image` to copy ext2/3/4 partitions (e.g. e2image -ra -p /dev/sda3 /dev/sdb3), or if you have GUI, use `gparted`.

For `fat32` partitions you can simply use `cp -a` (you'd have to format them first using `mkfs.vfat`).

Answer (score 1):

[CloneZilla](https://clonezilla.org/) can do the job. [Gparted](https://gparted.org/) could help.

From clonezilla.org :

> Clonezilla is a partition and disk imaging/cloning program similar to
> True Image® or Norton Ghost®. It helps you to do system deployment,
> bare metal backup and recovery. Three types of Clonezilla are
> available, **Clonezilla live**, Clonezilla lite server, and Clonezilla SE
> (server edition). Clonezilla live is suitable for single machine
> backup and restore.

Assuming you've the adapter and an free min. 512M USB stick, you can use [CloneZilla (live version)](https://clonezilla.org/downloads/download.php?branch=stable) in Disk2Disk mode aka **device-device**, with the grow option (expert mode : -r). The cloned disk will have all his space used (identical ratios from the old one). This is the quick and dirty method.

If you want more fine grain growing, use CloneZilla live in Disk2Disk mode and beginner mode. The clone disk will be the exact duplicate of the original. Then reboot on a gparted live USB and move/grow your partitions as you need. You can try doing this directly from your old disk as gparted is very easy to add in Ubuntu : `sudo apt-get install gparted` but as both disk will have the same UUID, I'm not sure the way gparted will react, but it worth a try.

Assuming you have sufficient old USB storage somewhere, You can forget the adapter, and use CZ in Disk2Image mode aka **device-image**, copy the parts on your old USB drive, then exchange the SSDs, and relaunch CZ in Image2Disk mode, then grow everything with gparted (on a live USB).

Flashing the .iso on an USB is very easy under linux (depending of distro and conf) :

- often, just right-click the .iso file and choose something like "disk image writer" (I've a non-english desktop for now), then choose the good drive to write to (the USB stick)
- with gnome or simillars, search gnome-disk-utility

Greetings,

Comment: Will using Gparted as a boot disk be any different than using it on Linux, or using another partition manager on Windows? Because no matter what I try, even if there is unallocated space before or after the partition, there is no way I can resize it. It won't let me.

Comment: @Christopher Kelly - You can't use gparted on mounted partitions. So it's often easier to use a live version (from gparted 'live', or many other live CD-DVD like a mint install, debian or knoppix live version). But when dealing with a another disk without mounted partitions (like the cloned one here), it can be done with the currently OS installed gparted.

Comment: Clonezilla and Gparted are experienced and long time projects aimed to do all that kind of manipulations, no matters what OS is installed. You can learn a lot reading what they automagicaly do (a lot of testing, pre-repairing, doing, comparing, re-testing and so on...) as everything is shown. And -for recent versions- they can deal with gpt partitions tables